# How to create multiple data frames (subsets) from one data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a very large data frame containing location data from 8 different ships. I want to split this data frame into 8 smaller data frames corresponding to the 8 ships that are represented in the data. I want these dataframes to have the same name as the ship that is represented in the data frame.

Comment: You can either just `groupby` on the ship names, or just make a list of the 8 chip names and construct a dict using the ship names as keys and the subset dfs as the dict values. Personally I'd avoid making multiple dfs unless there is a performance reason

Comment: Depending on usage there might be a privacy reason too for separation.
Assumed each ship has the option to see data from other ships, that might be undesired even by some laws perhaps.